# Typescript passing whole object vs single key when only single key is needed by React FC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, object

I am contemplating whether I should pass the whole object, vs passing the single required key of the object to my React Functional Component.
I know Typescript passes by reference so there is not any performance impact, but I want to know what is a better practice as far as programming paradigms and best practices are concerned.

The object in question is fairly big, having 11 keys. A couple of keys have objects and array of objects as values.

What I need in my FC is just a key of type string.

Comment: Try to pass the bare minimum that is needed for proper functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to React components it is best for the `props` to be data that is required by the component itself directly. What that means is if a component needs only the keys then give only them.

It is best to think for a component as its own world. That would help you in the future to update it or do something else. It will limit the possibility human mistakes that may occur while thinking for what the component’s job is. It will likely also allow you to reuse the component somewhere else.